# Application of Bayes Ball in the following example

Tags: bayesian, graphical-model

[image: Snippet from Murphy's Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective]

As shown in the image, Murphy explains that if 5 is given, then 2 and 6 are conditionally independent (CI), because paths 2-5-6, 2-4-7-6 and 2-1-3-6 are inaccesible. However, couldn't the information travel via the path 2-5-3-6? Since 5 is the child of 2 and 3, if 5 is known, then the information is reflected from 2 to 3 and then transmitted to 6? If there is anything wrong with my reasoning, I would appreciate if someone can point out where I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Murphy's assertion that $x_2 \perp x_6 \mid x_5 $ is incorrect. As you point out, observing $x_5$ activates the v-structure $2 \rightarrow 5 \leftarrow 3$, so the path $2 - 5 - 3 - 6 $ is active.

Furthermore, since $x_1$ is unobserved, the path $2 - 1 - 3 - 6 $ is also active! Since there are two active paths between $x_2$ and $x_6$, they are not d-separated and thus are not conditionally independent given $x_5$.